# Pass data from .cs file to cshtml file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I my application I am using aspx as well as mvc controller pages but now one scenario occurred where I have to pass data from both to my view cshtml. From controller I have used viewBag to pass data but I don't know how should i pass data from .cs file ?

Comment: Why not use your controller and/or code behind <-> cs file/library dll/etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this syntax:

```
public static class SomeClass {
     public string SomeMethod() {
          return "SomeValue";
     }
}
```

And get it in view:

```
@namespaceToFile.SomeClass.SomeMethod()
```

Comment: I ahve found another workaround here like :: Use     Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index") in aspx page while use RedirectToAction("Index","Home") in MVC controller.